# Turn on manually liquibase on runtime

Tags: java, spring, maven, liquibase

I'm developing a Spring boot app(using Maven) which uses Liquibase(which connect to Postgres container). I want to run liquibase manually on runtime but I don't really know how to do that. I want to have an option to trigger my app to run and start liquibase.

I've turned off liquibase on the application.properties file, it did stop liquibase from running on startup, but yet i didn't find any way to trigger it on runtime.

Comment: If you look how `SpringLiquibase` is created [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.java#L95) you can get basic idea how to execute in on runtime. Note that main method is executed in `#afterPropertiesSet`

Comment: After I looked there, what I understood was that when I set the spring.liquibase.enabled property to false the spring won't even create the SpringLiquibase bean. I can't use AnnotationConfigApplicationContext to get that Bean because those beans aren't even created. Can you please specify me what am I missing, or either what I don't understand good enough to see the solution.

Comment: maybe try to create some project on github and I can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Easy dude.

Manual updates with Liquibase allow you to control WHEN the database is updated, but WHAT is actually executed is still managed completely by Liquibase. For those who need to know exactly what is being done to their database, Liquibase supports an “`updateSQL`” mode in the command line, Ant, and Maven interfaces. When running `updateSQL`, Liquibase will simply output the SQL it would normally have ran. The output includes both the SQL to update your database and also the SQL to keep the DATABASECHANGELOG table up to date. Inspect the output as you need then execute it through whatever database tools you prefer. After running the SQL, your database will be in the correct state, and Liquibase will know what was ran and so future `updateSQL` calls will include only new changeSets.

Click link to get exact commands :http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html